# Troubles with dates in Java

Tags: java, date, syntax, simpledateformat

I have the next problem with dates when I work with java. I have this code:

```
String dateF=anio_final+"-12-31";
System.out.println("La fecha final al principio:"+dateF);

java.util.Date f_final=null;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
f_final=formatter.parse(dateF);
System.out.println("Al final la fecha final es:"+f_final);

//=> anio_final is 2012,
```

So when I print dateF I get 2012-12-31 but when I do the SimpleDateFormat to put it on the f_final variable I get 2012-01-31, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), month of the year is denoted by `Uppercase  M`. `Lowercase m` is for `minute`: -

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

should be: -

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: @zoit.. You're welcome. Always go through the documentation whenever you see weird results related to Java API. Documentation has almost always got answers for the problems.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Your pattern `yyyy-mm-dd` is: year - minute in hour - day in month :-) You should change to

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
```